# creating a labels.csv folder out of a local dataset

Tags: python, csv, deep-learning

i have a dataset on my drive that is divided into folders for each class. i want to create a .csv file that has the name of each image and its corresponding parent file aka the label.

this is what i have so far

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

name_list = []
label_list = []

img_dir = './content/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DRS/' #Directory of all images 
file_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'no DR', 'Mild NPDR', 'Moderate NPDR', 'Severe NPDR', 'PDR')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []

for file in files:
  label_list.append(img_dir)
  name_list.append(file)
   
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(name_list,columns=['image'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(label_list,columns=['label'])

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
result
result.to_csv('./content/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DRS/labels.csv', index = False)
```

the problems im having are that i dont want the entire pathname of the image, just imagename.jpg and no matter what i do the labels are showing up as './content/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DRS/'

this is one of my first deep learning projects so i'm not very familiar with the techniques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd list the directory with `os.listdir()` and make a CSV with `pandas`:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r'cats_and_dogs_dataset')

folders = ['dogs', 'cats']

files = []

for folder in folders:
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        files.append([file, folder])

pd.DataFrame(files, columns=['files', 'target']).to_csv('files_and_targets.csv')
```

The CSV would look like this:

```
              file target
0     dog.4001.jpg   dogs
1     dog.4002.jpg   dogs
2     dog.4003.jpg   dogs
3     dog.4004.jpg   dogs
4     dog.4005.jpg   dogs
```

Comment: thank you nicolas! i did what you recommended and i think it is pretty much what i need, however i have a level of subfolders in between the folders and the images (dog/cat breeds, for example),  for c in classes:
     `13     for subclass in os.listdir(c):
     14         for file in os.listdir(subclasses):
     15             files.append([file, subclass, c])`
and i'm getting an error saying 'No such file or directory' in line 13 although i'm sure the folder names match. do you happen to know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`filename_sting.split('/')` to create a vector with the filename divided by '/'.
E.g. :
 `"/home/usr/test.txt".split() = ['','home','usr','test.txt']`
You can then choose which parts to use and add them together again.

Edit:

I think I misunderstood. You want the filename but you only append the path that you specified above to `label_list`.
You probably want to use the `name_list' instead of the 'label_list`